# Using StreamProvder to get User auth changes

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am using `Wrapper` Class combined with `Firebase Streams` to redirect a user either to `LogInPage` or `HomePage`.

Below is `main.dart` and `Wrapper` Class.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<Users>.value(
      value: AuthenticationService(FirebaseAuth.instance).user,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<Users>(context);

    print(user == null ? "null id" : "${user.userId}");

    return user == null
        ? LoginPage()
        : HomePage();
  }
}
```

And below is my `Authentication Class` and the function from where I am calling the `authentication method`.

```
onTap: () async {
    dynamic user = await _auth.verifySMS(
      widget.verificationId,
      code,
      context,
    );
    if (user == null) {
      showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return CustomDialogBox(
          title: "Error",
          descriptions: "Can not Login now.",
             text: "Try Again",
             );
          });
       }
},

class AuthenticationService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  AuthenticationService(this._firebaseAuth);

  // Getting user from firebase
  Users _getUserFromFirebase(User user) {
    return user != null
        ? Users(
            userId: user.uid,
          )
        : null;
  }

  // Stream<User> get authStateChanges => _firebaseAuth.idTokenChanges();
  Stream<Users> get user {
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_getUserFromFirebase);
  }

// authentication methods which returns _getUserFromFirebase.
}
```

Upon successful verification I am able to print the correct `userId` from `Wrapper Class`. But instead of the second image I am getting the first one. Once I restart my app I am redirected to HomePage.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Socket connections doesn't work on emulators. No idea why. You will probably get your expected result if you test on a real device.

Comment: I have tested it even on a real device, but still getting the same result.

Comment: What is happening when you allow the location permission after logging in ?

Comment: the dialog button disappears and I stay on the `Submit Button` Page

Comment: It is a possibility that the dialog is restricting the flow. Because if its asking the permission for location, it is trying to initialize your Home page with google map. Try removing the map integration from the home page so that it wont show permission pop up and see if it works as expected. Notify if it works that way. If it does then it can be solved